# Can't read the actual value in Game maker Studio Firebase Realtime DataBase extension

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, gml, game-maker-studio-2

I don't know what I am doing wrong but whenever I want to read a value I get the reference instead and I don't know how to get the value from the database any other way
I am using the extension provided by yoyogames.

```
[var pth=FirebaseAuthentication_GetLocalId()
var ref= (FirebaseRealTime().Path(pth+"/money"))
money=ref.Read() //this return the reference instead of the value ]
```